# Assets in Template

Tags: assets

I am trying to create a portfolio site. I have set up field for image, description and  a link.

The description and link are being pulled through but the image is not working.  This is what I have for the images field:

```
{% for assets in entry.image %}
    <img class="portfolio-images" src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

This is the full entry:

```
<section class="portfolio-section" id="portfolio"> 
    <h2 id="opaque" style="color:white;">Here are a few of the projects I have been working on recently.</h2>
    <ul class="portfolio Grid">

        {% for entry in craft.entries.section('portfolio').limit(9) %}
            <li class="portfolio-item Grid-item Grid-third">
                <div class="portfolio-info">
                    <h3 class="portfolio-title">{{entry.title}}</h3>

                    {% for assets in entry.image %}
                        <img class="portfolio-images" src="{{ asset.url }}">
                    {% endfor %}

                    {{entry.description}}
                </div>

                <a href="{{entry.website_link}}" target="_blank"><button class="button" type="button">View website</button> </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</section>
```

Why is the text and link working but the image not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are looping through `entry.image` with the key `assets` but inside your loop you are trying to access the URL on `asset`. These need to be the same.

```
{% for asset in entry.image %}
  <img class="portfolio-images" src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have have tired various versions/combinations with no luck. What is the correct code please?

Comment: Have you checked the fieldname is correct? Try adding `{{ entry.image|length }}` to your template and see what the result is.

Comment: Hi Luke, Thanks but I tried that and still no luck.  The field name is correct.  I'll try adding   | length  and see how I get on.

Comment: Do you have devMode on? Luke's answer should've done the trick unless the field name is incorrect or there is no asset.

Comment: When I add  {{ entry.image | length }}  I get 1 displayed on the page.  Sorry I very new to this.

Comment: That means that there is in fact something there. Can you turn devMode on? That would give you some insight as to if there are any errors.

Comment: Thank you!  I figured it out, it was an error in my asset settings! I am very new to Craft and still trying to figure out what I am doing.